# I am having trouble installing animation nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

I am trying to install the animation nodes addon on my mac, but I keep getting this error message
[image]

I cannot find the specified folders on my mac and would really like some help if anyone knows what the heck to do.

Comment: The path for the addon folder is mentioned in the error message, go to the addon folder and removed the animation_nodes folder. If you still have the issue then please report on AN GitHub page: https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/issues

Comment: Check this thread too for common issues https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/issues/1240